# generate all sequences of length 3 from the alpha set {A,B} in java

Tags: java, permutation, sequences

I have the following task.

Input: {A,B} and 3.

Output: all the following sequences: (A,A,A), (A,A,B), (A,B,A), (A,B,B), (B,A,A), (B,A,B), (B,B,A), (B,B,B).

So far, what I can think is to use recursion. We start with a null root node. Then, we add three more levels, with each level corresponding to a entry for the to be created sequence. Each node has two children, one has value A and the other one has value B. Then, each path from the root to the leaf vertex is a sequence we are looking for.

Any more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: As it's a set of two, you could think binary. A=0, B=1, then just count upwards in binary.

Comment: @Phil_1984, thanks very much for your comment. Your idea does not only apply to a set of two, right? I mean, if the set is of three, we can think of another number system based on it. I guess it's the same thing though.

Comment: Yep, all you're doing here is counting in various bases.

Comment: Yes.  If it was A, B & C, you could count in Ternary (base 3), 000, 001, 002, 010, 011, etc

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an alphabet to work with
        char[] alphabet = new char[] {'a','b'};
        // Find all possible combinations of this alphabet in the string size of 3
        StringExcersise.possibleStrings(3, alphabet,"");
    }

}
 class StringExcersise {

    public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr) {

        // If the current string has reached it's maximum length
        if(curr.length() == maxLength) {
            System.out.println(curr);

        // Else add each letter from the alphabet to new strings and process these new strings again
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                String oldCurr = curr;
                curr += alphabet[i];
                possibleStrings(maxLength,alphabet,curr);
                curr = oldCurr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```